How to get back my old branch after a failed git rebase
I have the following situation: I rebased the feature branch my-branch on master using
git rebase master

from my-branch.
However I'm not happy with the result (AFTER), so what I want is to get back to the previous situation where my-branch had C as a parent instead of F (see below). But my-branch is now refering to the branch with E' and H'.

Before                                    After
A---B---C---F---G (master)                A---B---C---F---G (master)
         \                                        |    \
          D---E (HEAD my-branch)                  \     E'----H' (my-branch, HEAD)
                                                   \
                                                    \---E-----H (ORIG_HEAD)

The usual recommendation is to use
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD

But then I'm in detached head state and my-branch is still pointing to H'. I can't just create the same branch my-branch again that already exists if I'm not mistaken. So what options do I have?
EDIT: I was mistaken. I did a git checkout to the ORIG_HEAD before, that's why the branch was not reset properly. The above does the job just right.

Short answer just upon reading the question title: reflog (in case ORIG_HEAD is unset/not what you expected)

You have to abort your rebasement:
git rebase --abort
If you already applied your rebasement do a reflog and get back to the commit hash you want:
git reflog
git reset --hard hash_of_commit
It should work, good luck

But that doesn't change my-branch from pointing to HEAD instead of ORIG_HEAD right?

git reflog shows you all the commits - you can then git reset <the commit>. Would be a good idea to add this to the answer, to be complete :).

I don't have enough reputations to leave this as a comment.
Check this if this helps.
Undoing a git rebase

Indeed git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD works just fine, I was mistaken :)
